# Understanding an answer to a linear algebra problem

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Show that if $(I - M)^{-1}$
>   doesn't exist, then there is $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $x \neq 0$ such
>   that $(I - M)x = 0$. Use this result to show $||M|| \geq 1$

The answer is very short:

If $(I - M)$ is singular, there is $x \neq 0 $ with $(I -M)x = 0$, where $x = Mx$. Thus, $||x|| = ||Mx|| \leq ||M|| \cdot ||x||$ and dividing by $||x||$ gives the result.

How did they deduce $x = Mx$?

Comment: The Invertible Matrix Theorem guarantees us such an $x.$

Comment: I thought that IMT had a bunch of statements equivalent to what invertibility meant? Here, we have noninvertibility. Also, I thought IMT just said for an invertible matrix $A$, $Ax = x$ has only the trivial solution. How would you get something like $x = Ax$ from that?

Comment: If $(I - M)x = 0$ then $Ix - Mx = 0$ or $Ix = Mx$. Since $Ix = x$, we have that $x = Mx$.

Comment: It does, and one of those statements is that $(I-M)$ is invertible if and only if there is no $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with $x\not=0$ and $(I-M)x=0.$ Use the contrapositive of that statement.

Comment: Ok I think I get it. But Isn't it sort of strange to be defining $x$ in terms of $x$ itself?

Comment: We're not really defining such an $x.$ We're saying there must exist an $x$ with the properties, but not one says what it is. So there is no real circular definition.

Comment: It is just a matter of "unfortunate" writing style. Just replace "where $x= Mx$" by "which implies $x= Mx$"